# How to add SHIRO realm request time out for user authentication?

Tags: java, shiro

In my shiro.ini, I configured 2 realm i.e. LDAP and JDBC

But I am not able to set the authentication request time out.

When I added: ldapRealm.connectionTimeout = 1000
then it throws exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener
```

org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Property 'connectionTimeout' does not exist for object of type com.bc.xyz.auth.efgLdapRealm.
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.isTypedProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:413)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:702)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:364)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:325)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$AssignmentStatement.doExecute(ReflectionBuilder.java:955)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$Statement.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:887)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfigurationProcessor.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:765)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:260)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:221)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a custom LDAP Realm, does your `efgLdapRealm` have a `setConnectionTimeout()` method?

Comment: No, I don't have that method.